# How can I make this code more efficient?

Tags: arrays, arduino, coding-efficiency

I have two questions relating to the code below. First, I understand that this code is horrid and can be reduced and improved. I want to be able to add the entire alphabet, and numbers, but typing out every single one would be stupid.

First question: How can I shorten this code? I am not really familiar with arrays, but I'm guessing that is what I would work with.

Second question: How do I use an array to represent each letter/number?

Thank you all.

```
/*
Blinks "BRENTON" in Morse Code, in pin # 12. 
 */

void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  // Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards:
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

int dot = 250;
int dash = dot * 3;
int space = dot * 7;
int rest = 250;

void A() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(space);
}
void B() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(space);
}
void R() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(space);
}
void E() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(space);
}
void N() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dot);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(space);
} 
void T() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(space);
}
void O() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(rest);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  delay(dash);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  delay(space);
}
void pin13(){
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(10000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
void loopOne() {
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 100) {
    pin13();
    i++;
  }
}

void loop() {
  B();
  R();
  E();
  N();
  T();
  O();
  N();
}
```

Comment: You should ask [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: would you please just google "arduino morse".... its not that difficult https://gist.github.com/madc/4474559 and other hits will give more than enough inspiration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for improvements on working code belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Morse code generator some years back for a friend who was into geocaching.  This code controlled a transmitter.  While it is in C, perhaps it will give you some insight into how to do this.  You really only need three routines, one for 'dit', 'dah' and 'space.'

`play_space` is really nothing but turning off the sound and a short delay.

`play_mark` is really nothing but turning on the sound with a duration, and could be coded in Arduino as `tone(pin, frequency, duration_milliseconds)`.

All the stuff in `init` is just setting up the controller to play tones at a set frequency.  Again, easier on the Arduino with `tone()`.  The main thing is the representation of each character and numeral in the `MCode` struct and array of them.  Then for each character in the string you want to send, you just search down the array until you find the matching character and then play the `code` from the struct using `xmit_symbol()`.

```
#define F_CPU 1000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// transmission lengths, in milliseconds
#define DIT_MS 60                       // dit length of 120 should yield ~10 words per minute
#define DAH_MS (DIT_MS * 3)     // dah length
#define AL_SPACE (DIT_MS * 3)   // after-letter space
#define AW_SPACE (DIT_MS * 6)   // after-word space = 6 + after-letter space = 7

// simple diagnostic LED 
#define LED_1   PA0

// hardcoded callsign
const char* CALLSIGN = "HELLO WORLD";

static const struct
{
    const char symbol;
    const uint8_t length;
    const uint8_t code;

} MCode[] = 
{
    {'A', 2, 0b01000000},
    {'B', 4, 0b10010000},
    {'C', 4, 0b10100000},
    {'D', 3, 0b10000000},
    {'E', 1, 0b00000000},
    {'F', 4, 0b00100000},
    {'G', 3, 0b11000000},
    {'H', 4, 0b00000000},
    {'I', 2, 0b00000000},
    {'J', 4, 0b01110000},
    {'K', 3, 0b10100000},
    {'L', 4, 0b01000000},
    {'M', 2, 0b11000000},
    {'N', 2, 0b10000000},
    {'O', 3, 0b11100000},
    {'P', 4, 0b01100000},
    {'Q', 4, 0b11010000},
    {'R', 3, 0b01000000},
    {'S', 3, 0b00000000},
    {'T', 1, 0b10000000},
    {'U', 3, 0b00100000},
    {'V', 4, 0b00010000},
    {'W', 3, 0b01100000},
    {'X', 4, 0b10010000},
    {'Y', 4, 0b10110000},
    {'Z', 4, 0b11000000},
    {'1', 5, 0b01111000},
    {'2', 5, 0b00111000},
    {'3', 5, 0b00011000},
    {'4', 5, 0b00001000},
    {'5', 5, 0b00000000},
    {'6', 5, 0b10000000},
    {'7', 5, 0b11000000},
    {'8', 5, 0b11100000},
    {'9', 5, 0b11110000},
    {'0', 5, 0b11111000},
    {'-', 6, 0b10000100}
};


void init(void)
{
    // set up diagnostic led
    DDRA |= (1<<LED_1);
    // set up OC1A pin as output for PWM signal
    DDRB |= (1<<PB1);
    // set up fast PWM mode
    TCCR1A |= (1<<PWM1A);
    // timer1 prescaler
    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12);    //  1/8 (yields ~490Hz at 1MHz FCPU) (p.117)
    // set OCR value to achieve close enough to square wave
    OCR1A = 128;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////  ROUTINES TO CREATE MARKS AND SPACES
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void play_space(uint16_t length)
{
    // play a space of the specified length
    PORTA &= ~(1<<LED_1);
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<COM1A1);
    _delay_ms(length);
}

void play_mark(uint16_t length)
{
    // play a mark for specified length
    PORTA |= (1<<LED_1);
    TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1A1);
    _delay_ms(length);
    // always play a dit-length space afterwards
    PORTA &= ~(1<<LED_1);
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<COM1A1);
    _delay_ms(DIT_MS);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////  TRANSMIT A CHARACTER AND INTER-CHARACTER SPACE
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void xmit_symbol(uint8_t length, uint8_t code)
{
    for (uint8_t p = 0; p < length; p++)
    {
        uint8_t shift = 7 - p;
        uint8_t mask = 1<<shift;
        uint8_t result = code & mask;
        if (result == mask)
            play_mark(DAH_MS);
        else
            play_mark(DIT_MS);
    }
    play_space(AL_SPACE);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////  TRANSMIT A NULL-TERMINATED STRING
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void xmit_callsign()
{
    uint8_t iStringPos;
    uint8_t iSearchPos;

    // Process each character of the callsign string.
    // NOTE: Trick here uses null terminator on string to make comparison false.
    for (iStringPos = 0; CALLSIGN[iStringPos]; iStringPos++)
    {
        // Linear search through array of structs seeking matching symbol.
        for (iSearchPos = 0; iSearchPos < (sizeof MCode / sizeof *MCode); iSearchPos++ )
        {
            if (CALLSIGN[iStringPos] == MCode[iSearchPos].symbol)
            {
                // We found a match, so transmit this character/symbol.
                xmit_symbol(MCode[iSearchPos].length, MCode[iSearchPos].code);

                // Bail out and move on down the string until done...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////  MAIN LOOP
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(void)
{
    // Initialize the controller.
    init();

    // Endless main loop.
    while(1)
    {
        // 3-second delay in before starting, for ease in copying...
        for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) _delay_ms(1000);

        // call central transmit routine
        xmit_callsign();

        // insert a hard delay in between transmissions, for now
        for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) _delay_ms(1000);
    }
    // required but unreachable
    return 0;
}
```